# Oracle Data Integrator (ODI - v11.1.1.3) "unable to load language: beanshell" Error

Tags: oracle, etl, oracle-data-integrator

Following an install of Eclipse 3.7.2 on my Ubuntu 12.04 development machine, I have been unable to execute any ODI packages/interfaces/procedures. On execution (for both simulated and actual runs), an error is thrown (java trace below). I am not sure if it's anything to do with the Eclipse install, but it seems likely. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Also, when launching ODI from the terminal using 'bash odi', the following error is displayed in the terminal:

```
 2013-08-15 14:43:46.162 ERROR Error during RuntimeClassLoader initialization. ODI will start without RuntimeClassLoader
```

**Error output:**

```
oracle.odi.core.exception.OdiRuntimeException: Error during Code Interpretor creation
at com.sunopsis.dwg.codeinterpretor.SnpCodeInterpretor.getInstance(SnpCodeInterpretor.java:209)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.codeinterpretor.SnpGeneratorSQLCIT.<init>(SnpGeneratorSQLCIT.java:300)
at com.sunopsis.graphical.dialog.SnpsDialogExecution.doPackageExecuter(SnpsDialogExecution.java:907)
at oracle.odi.ui.action.SnpsPopupActionExecuteHandler.actionPerformed(SnpsPopupActionExecuteHandler.java:68)
at oracle.odi.ui.SnpsActionControler.handleEvent(SnpsActionControler.java:75)
at oracle.ide.controller.IdeAction.performAction(IdeAction.java:529)
at oracle.ide.controller.IdeAction.actionPerformedImpl(IdeAction.java:884)
at oracle.ide.controller.IdeAction.actionPerformed(IdeAction.java:501)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:357)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:809)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:850)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6297)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6062)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2039)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4660)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4236)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4166)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2083)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:674)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:647)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:645)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:644)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.apache.bsf.BSFException: unable to load language: beanshell
at org.apache.bsf.BSFManager.loadScriptingEngine(BSFManager.java:718)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.codeinterpretor.SnpCodeInterpretor.loadEngine(SnpCodeInterpretor.java:85)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.codeinterpretor.SnpCodeInterpretor.<init>(SnpCodeInterpretor.java:75)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.codeinterpretor.SnpCodeInterpretor.getInstance(SnpCodeInterpretor.java:184)
... 45 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around for about a day on this issue, I brazenly tried running ODI as the root user on the off chance that this was a permissions issue. I started ODI from the command line (using 'bash odi') for greater verbosity, and it loaded without the error mentioned above. Something gave me the impression that this wasn't a permissions issue, but one related to the user settings.

To rectify the issue, I removed my user's odi settings folder (renaming it, for safety):

```
mv ~/.odi ~/.backup_odi
```

Then I started ODI from the terminal under my own user (i.e. not root) - there were no errors! None of my connections were available in the new settings folder though. This I fixed by closing ODI and entering the following:

```
cp ~/.backup_odi/oracledi/snps_login_work.xml ~/.odi/oracledi/
```

If anybody else encounters this issue, I hope you find this post quicker than it took me to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

```
org.apache.bsf.BSFException: unable to load language: beanshell
```

The exception was thrown because `bsh-2.Ob4.jar` was not in the classpath and it is a dependent jar of `bsf.jar`